# Multidimensional array and usage in PHP

Tags: php

I need to figure out the best way to put together an array where multiple keys have the same value. For example,I need to return ***LARGE*** if any of the following values are provided:

```
"lrge", "lrg", "lg"
```

I think it should be in a form of multidimensional array. Something like:

```
$myArr= array (
    "color" = array (
       "RED"   => array("red", "rd", "r"),
       "BLUE"  => array("blue", "blu", "bl")
    ),
    "size" = array (
       "LARGE" => array("lrge", "lrg", "lg"),
       "SMALL" => array("smal", "sml", "sm")
    )
);
```

Having a blank moment on how to use it:

```
$cat = "size";    
$val = "lrg";

echo ... // need to return LARGE
```

Comment: Is it known whether your input value is a color or a size?  Or is it unknown?

Comment: Actually, this is a very good question. I will know whether it's COLOR or SIZE. I'll update post...

Comment: Also, is it possible for you to use a database for this instead of hardcoded arrays?

Comment: [`foreach`](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) and [`in_array()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php) are your best friends for this task. But for bonus points I would change the format of the list to express the mapping in the other direction.

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot use db here. I get a value via API and I'm just trying to normalize the output.

Comment: I think it's better to use a lookup table than rolling out an array based solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Personally, I'd look into storing these mappings in a database.  Long-term, it will probably make your life easier.  However, since you already know which attribute you want to be searching, this is actually rather trivial.  Just loop through the sub-array specified by your `$cat` variable, and then use [`in_array()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php) to see if `$val` is in that row.

```
$myArr= array (
    "color" => array (
       "RED"   => array("red", "rd", "r"),
       "BLUE"  => array("blue", "blu", "bl")
    ),
    "size" => array (
       "LARGE" => array("lrge", "lrg", "lg"),
       "SMALL" => array("smal", "sml", "sm")
    )
);

$cat = "size";    
$val = "lrg";

$match = "";

foreach($myArr[$cat] as $key => $row)
{
    if(in_array($val, $row))
    {
        $match = $key;
        break;
    }
}

echo $match;
```

[DEMO](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/3dbec03b4dec0d841def32f3ee8b326fac0b952e)

Answer (score 2):

If the only use of `$myArr` is to map the values you get from the API to some standard values then the best approach is to create a lookup table that maps the input values to the desired normalized values:

```
$myArr = array(
    'color' => array(
         'red'  => 'RED',  'rd'  => 'RED',  'r'  => 'RED',
         'blue' => 'BLUE', 'blu' => 'BLUE', 'bl' => 'BLUE',
    ),
    'size' => array(
         'lrge' => 'LARGE', 'lrg' => 'LARGE', 'lg' => 'LARGE',
         'smal' => 'SMALL', 'sml' => 'SMALL', 'sm' => 'SMALL',
    ),
);
```

This way, the normalization is as simple as:

```
$cat = 'size';
$val = 'lrg';

$normal = $myArr[$cat][$val];
```

Comment: Although I accepted the other answer, it's just because it was addressing exactly my question. However, after seeing this post I may change my approach to avoid loops. +1